# Customize date_i18n format in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, date-format

I want to change the format of the date from '15 June 2018 to 15-06-2018' because i have a multilingual website and my code returns date only in English. here is the code :

`$expiry = date_i18n(wc_date_format(), strtotime('+'.$expiry.' days'));`

this code returns '15 June 2018' i don't know if we can add something like :

`wc_date_format(d, m, y)`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way tp get what you expect is replacing `wc_date_format()` by `'d-m-Y'` in your code:

```
$expiry = date_i18n( 'd-m-Y', strtotime('+'.$expiry.' days') );
```

This time **you will get 15-06-2018** instead of 15 June 2018.

Comment: Yes Yes it worked, i was expecting ur reply :) Thanks